# keycloak-angular: Check if user is logged in before app is bootstrapped

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-angular

I want to check if user logged in before the app is bootstrapped, so I add `keycloak.isLoggedIn()` in `APP_INITIALIZER`, but it always returns `false` even if user is logged in.
Need to clear local storage before login if a user is not authenticated. Or maybe some other idea how to clean the local storage if the user has logged out on another environment

```
export function appInit(
  keycloak: KeycloakService,
  auth: AuthenticationService): () => Promise<any> {
  return async () => {
    try {
      
      const authenticated = await keycloak.isLoggedIn();
      if (!authenticated) {
        localStorage.clear();
      }

      await keycloak
        .init({
          config: {
            url: environment.keycloakUrl + '/auth',
            realm: environment.keycloakRealm,
            clientId: environment.keycloakClientId
          },
          initOptions: {
            onLoad: 'login-required',
            silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
          },
          enableBearerInterceptor: true,
        })
        .then(async (success) => {
```

Versions.
"keycloak-angular": "^9.3.2",
"keycloak-js": "^16.1.1",

Tried to check in app.component.ts, but this is too late, need to make it in `APP_INITIALIZER`.